# can't do getNextSibling() because of null

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception

i am traversing an xml tree using java..right now i am having trouble in getting the node's sibling using node.getPreviousSibling(),here is the code :

```
sibling = pointer.getPreviousSibling();
while (sibling==null){
                    System.out.println("YAAAAAA");

                    sibling = sibling.getPreviousSibling(); ///here is the error occured
                }
```

the error was NullPointerException.
i know that getPreviousSibling() could return null if there is no sibling..
the question is :

1. why sibling.getPreviousSibling() gave me an error instead of assign the null value into test Node without giving me an exception?
2. what should i do so that my code will run just fine even if it's looping forever because the sibling will always null?

thank you..

EDIT 1 : before the code above,i already checked if the pointer is null or not

```
if(pointer==null){
System.out.println("NULL");
}
```

but still,it shows that the pointer wasn't a null..
so i wonder what triggers the NullPointerException

EDIT 2 : i figured another way,and it seems that i make mistake somehow when assigning the pointer (not sure which one is the mistake, but i'm sure there is a mistake)
my new way is by getting the node parent using

```
Node parent =pointer.getParentNode();
```

from there i choose which child that i want..

thanks to @almas and @demostene for pointing out i'm calling getPreviousSibling the wrong way

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Find the "previous-most" sibling?

Comment: my code supposed to find the sibling if the current node is not the node that i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for non null and not for null in your while loop like:

```
while (sibling != null && sibling.getPreviousSibling() != null){
```

instead of

```
while (sibling==null){
```

Comment: Probably the right direction, but even then `sibling` will end up being `null`. It probably should even be `while (sibling.getPreviousSibling() != null)` (provided that `pointer != null`)

Comment: @tobias_k I agree so OP gets the last sibling else will end up as null.

Comment: @almasshaikh why should i change it into != ?
i think i want to find the node which isn't null that's why i use ==
or did i miss something or i got it wrong?please explain..thanks

Comment: @adiyaka.ihsan if you dont use != null check then say your sibling would be null and you would try to access previous sibling via getPreviousSibling method on null and hence result in null pointer exception.

Comment: @almasshaikh thanks,,i figured out another way of acquiring the node that i want,,and also,now i realized that i was accessing the sibling of the node which is null. and that's why i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getPreviousSibling()` on a null object because the code loops until `sibling` becomes not null.

Comment: so the error because the current node the pointer was in before i call getPreviousSibling() is null?so it can't getPreviousSibling() because it is null?